# Combining scatter and line chart in JFreeChart using DynamicReports

Tags: java, jfreechart, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReports, whose chart based on JFreeChart. I want to draw chart like image link:

[image: Combining scatter and line chart image]

Comment: You might get better answers if you try to [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Look under _Statistical Charts_ in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).